# Android date format using SimpleDate

Tags: android, simpledateformat

I am working on an XML Parser for Android with twelve different items and I need help creating a date for each item. This is what I have so far:

`TextView detailsPubdate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detailspubdate);`

I am looking to make the date look like this: Saturday, September 3.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are looking for todays date, you can do this by using the `Date` object.

```
Date today = new Date();//this creates a date representing this instance in time.
```

Then pass the date to the `SimpleDateFormat.format(Date)` method.

```
// "EEEE, MMMM, d" is the pattern to use to get your desired formatted date.
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM, d");
String formattedDate = sdf.format(today);
```

Finally, you can set this `String` into your `TextView`

```
detailsPubdate.setText(formattedDate);
```

Here is the documentation for [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).  The documentation shows the various patterns available to format `Date` objects.

Comment: SimpleDateFormat is not thread safe, make sure you surround it with  synchronized.

Answer (score 2):

use the DateFormat class to format your dates.

Example:

```
     DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d");
    Date date = (Date) formatter.parse("02.47.44 PM");
detailsPubdate.setText(date.toString());
```

This is the java documentation for [SimpleDateFormatter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) if you want to change your pattern.

Answer (score 1):

It is not very clear what you are trying to do, but you could use the following to format date:

```
   SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM, d");
   //get current date
   Date date=new Date();
   String dateString=sdf.format(date);
```

You should have a look at the [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class.